# Update nested list of objects using java stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this class:

```
public class StructUserType extends UserType {

    MembersList membersList = new MembersList();

    public List<Member> getMembers() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(membersList.members);
    }

    static class MembersList {
        List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static class Member implements Identifiable {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        //getters and setters
    }    
}
```

And I have a `List` of object:

```
List<UserType> userTypes = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want update `Member` object which is equal to a certain id. For example, update the `name` field of member by id. How I can update nested list using `stream` api?

**UPDATE:**

I did this:

In class `StructUserType` I created one method:

```
void updateMember(Member member) {
        membersList.members.stream()
                .filter(m -> m.getId().equals(member.getId()))
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(m -> {
                    m.setName(member.getName());
                    m.setUserTypeId(member.getUserTypeId());
                });
    }
```

Also for external clients created a public method:

```
public void updateMemberOfStructUserType(StructUserType.Member member) {
        userTypes.stream()
                .filter(StructUserType.class::isInstance)
                .map(StructUserType.class::cast)
                .filter(st -> st.getMembers()
                        .stream()
                        .anyMatch(m -> m.getId().equals(member.getId())))
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(structUserType -> structUserType.updateMember(member));
    }
```

Comment: What is `userTypes` and the type `SmbpUserType`?  What does that have to do with `StructUserType`?  Do you have any code attempts at a streams solution, or any thoughts about how you might code it?

Comment: Can you update your question to provide a general overview of level of nesting that you are talking about? In the question I can see a list `List<Member>` and that's about it.

Comment: @Raf, I have `List<UserType`>, UserType contains `List<Member>`. I want update `member` by `Id` of this `member`, for example, set new `name` field. I updated my question, how can I made this. But I think, my method not optimal.

Comment: Much better. What is the result you are getting when you run this? Does it not update? Or you are getting an exception or some other result?

Comment: @Raf, It's work perfect, it update. But, I think this is not the optimal solution, because In fact, the same filter works twice in the first method, and then in the second.

Comment: So you find the `member` to be updated in this method `updateMemberOfStructUserType` and then you pass it to `updateMember` method and then you `stream` again. If the two methods share the same instance of `membersList.members` then you should be able to obtain (in updateMember method) the object by 1) `int idx = membersList.members.indexOf(member);` and 2) `membersList.member.get(idx);` and update it. You might need to override `equals` and `hashcode`. Not sure if this make sense, obviously it will depend on structure of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatmap the `userTypes` in the public update method and pass a stream of members to a common private `updateMember` method:

```
private void updateMember(Member member, Stream<Member> membersStream){
    membersStream.filter(m -> m.getId().equals(member.getId()))
        .findFirst()                
        .ifPresent(m -> {
            m.setName(member.getName());
            m.setUserTypeId(member.getUserTypeId());
        });
}

void updateMember(Member member) {
    updateMember(member, membersList.members.stream());        
}

public void updateMemberOfStructUserType(StructUserType.Member member) {
    Stream<Member>  membersStream = userTypes.stream()
        .filter(StructUserType.class::isInstance)
        .map(StructUserType.class::cast)
        .flatMap(st -> st.getMembers().stream());    
    updateMember(member, membersStream);
}
```